# W3 Total Cache does not combine / minify child theme CSS

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have a child theme and W3 Total Cache does all the combining and minification of all the parent theme's CSS files, but the style.css file of my child theme remains outside the combined and minified file. This also breaks my styles, because the order of inclusion of the CSS files is broken. This is how I have included the CSS files of the parent theme - I added the following line in my child theme's functions.php:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

global $wp_styles;
$parent_style = 'parent-style';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Is there another way of linking the CSS files so that they get properly intercepted by W3 Total Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try enabling @import handling for child themes**.

You also dont need to enqueue the style.css for child theme as its enqueued by default. Instead just enqueue the parent stylesheet.

```
// Child-theme Functions.php
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    global $wp_styles;
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Comment: I don't use @import for getting the parent styles. My child theme does have its own style.css, but I want to include the parent theme styles, and cascade my styles over them. This is why I included my CSS with the parent styles, and the way I did it is the recommended I found (e.g. here: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/164059/child-theme-does-not-overwrite-parent-themes-style-css))

Comment: Thats a hack and not a recommended way, and it totally violates the whole point of having priorities and dependencies in the first place. It also makes you stick to a specific child theme. Secondly i think w3total cache automatically imports your child theme even if you dont do it your self from within styles.css, so you should enable it.

Comment: So what is the "legal" and suggested way - through @import?

Comment: No the recommended way is to enqueue the parent style through parent theme and child style through the child theme with dependencies. Then allow import, and hopefully it will automatically import the child style inside the parent in the correct order.

Comment: Am I not doing just that with the code I presented above? Can you give an example?

Comment: One more thing you can do is to remove the second enqueue line from your code as style.css is automatically enqueued on the active theme.

Comment: Oh, yes! Excluding the enqueueing of the child style.css did the trick - thank you very much!

PS: I had \@import enabled before, but that didn't help - I am actually not using \@import to get the parent styles.

Comment: @omerFarooq - Where/how do you "enable \@import handling for child themes"? Is this something that is done by the code you provided above, or is it a WordPress setting, or a W3 Total Cache setting somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: @Drewdavid Its a w3 cache setting. that can be found under css minification